# Why isn't Vavr Either is recognizing the parameter to map() function?

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, either, vavr

I am dirtying my hands with the fantastic library of vavr (0.9.2).

Here's a code snippet, that aims to collect an *Either*:

```
    Either<Tuple2<Enum<ReportByTeamExecutionErrors>,String>, List<MayurDAO>> payloadPreparationResult =
    new ReportByTeamCriteriaSchemaChecker("./json/schema/REQ_ReportByTeam_Schema.json")
    .validateSchema(payLoad) // payload is JSON and is a paramter to this holding function
.map(JsonPOJOBidirectionalConverter::pojofyCriteriaAllFieldsTeam)
.map((e) -> {
        CriteriaTeamAllFieldsValidator validator =  new CriteriaTeamAllFieldsValidator(e.right().get());
        return(validator.validate());
 })
 .map((e) -> retrieveRecordsAsPerCriteria(e.right().get())) // compiler doesn't approve of this line!!
 ;
```

The *retrieveRecordsAsPerCriteria* method is defined this way:

```
private Either<Tuple2<Enum<ReportByTeamExecutionErrors>,String>, List<MayurDAO>>
    retrieveRecordsAsPerCriteria(CriteriaAllFieldsTeam criteriaAllFieldsTeam) {

        Optional<List<MayurDAO>> retrievedRecords = new MayurModel().retrieveRecords(criteriaAllFieldsTeam);

        return( (retrievedRecords.isPresent())
                ? (Either.right(retrievedRecords.get()))
                : Either.left(
                        Tuple.of(
                             ReportByTeamExecutionErrors.NO_RECORDS_FOUND_TO_MATCH_CRITERIA,
                             "No records have been found, which match the criteria passed"
                        )
                       )
            );
    }
```

The compiler is complaining:

> ./com/myApp/application/ReportByTeamResource.java:58: error:
>   incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) L,R
>                   .map((e) -> retrieveRecordsAsPerCriteria(e.right().get()));
>                       ^
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)   where L,R are type-variables:
>       L extends Object declared in method right(R)
>       R extends Object declared in method right(R) 1 error

The List is from java.util.List.

I am at my wit's end to understand the source of the problem. The types should easily inferred, or so I think.

[image]

IntelliJ seems to be OK with the transformations till this objectionable line! In that line, however, the type parameter U is not decipherable.
Could someone please nudge me to the path I am unable to see, for some reason?

Comment: Looks like quite some convoluted types with the nested Eithers. 

The thing that can make your snippet compile would be to replace the final `map` by a `flatMap`. But maybe it's a better idea to replace the nested `Either`, probably have a look at `flatMap` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you might want to use `flatMap` instead of `map`. The advantage of `flatMap` is that you don't get the nested eithers which you then need to *unwrap* in some way (like you are currently doing with `.right().get()` in your current code).

So the code would look something like this then:

```
Either<Tuple2<Enum<ReportByTeamExecutionErrors>,String>, List<MayurDAO>> payloadPreparationResult =
new ReportByTeamCriteriaSchemaChecker("./json/schema/REQ_ReportByTeam_Schema.json")
    .validateSchema(payLoad)
    .flatMap(JsonPOJOBidirectionalConverter::pojofyCriteriaAllFieldsTeam)
    .flatMap(e -> {
        CriteriaTeamAllFieldsValidator validator =  new CriteriaTeamAllFieldsValidator(e);
        return (validator.validate());
    })
    .flatMap(this::retrieveRecordsAsPerCriteria)
```

Comment: Yes, flatMap works - and many thanks for that - but doesn't it sound rather counter-intuitive? Well, from the Javadoc: _flatMap_ returns 'this as Either<L, U> if this is a Left, otherwise the right mapping result', whereas _map_ returns 'a mapped Monad'! This probably explains it, because map is kind of 'wrapping' it again! I don't know if that is the correct behaviour.

Comment: With `map` you transfrom the value if it's a right (success). But the `map` operations cannot indicate failure in terms of a `Left`. 

That is where the `flatMap` comes in. If you want your transforming operation to indicate success failure with an Either you should use flatMap. This will make sure that you will get a _flat_ `Either` back (instead of a nested `Either). Hence the name _flatMap_.

Comment: Agreed. I understand that I ended my earlier comment, rather confusingly. Apologies. The map() returns a Monad, but I am looking for a definite projection (Left or Right). Therefore, what I could have done was to use a pattern-matching inside the mapper and return an explicit Left or Right. Of course, in such a case, I would perhaps repeat myself while treating the 'Left's! A flatMap() saves me from all that, because till the end I am not interested about what does Either's LeftProjection contains. Thanks for taking time to elaborate your point.